# Failed to start Samba SMB Daemon. Failed with result 'exit-code'

Tags: 18.04, samba

My ubuntu was working fine, I logged in a shell and found that some packages could be upgraded so I launched an `apt update && apt upgrade` and after a while I got an error:

```
fmf@kodi:~$ sudo apt upgrade
[sudo] password for fmf:
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
Calculating upgrade... Done
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
1 not fully installed or removed.
After this operation, 0 B of additional disk space will be used.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n]
Setting up samba (2:4.7.6+dfsg~ubuntu-0ubuntu2.3) ...
Samba is not being run as an AD Domain Controller.
Please ignore the following error about deb-systemd-helper not finding samba-ad-dc.service.
Job for smbd.service failed because the control process exited with error code.
See "systemctl status smbd.service" and "journalctl -xe" for details.
invoke-rc.d: initscript smbd, action "start" failed.
● smbd.service - Samba SMB Daemon
   Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/smbd.service; disabled; vendor preset: enabled)
   Active: failed (Result: exit-code) since Wed 2018-11-07 17:05:30 CET; 25ms ago
     Docs: man:smbd(8)
           man:samba(7)
           man:smb.conf(5)
  Process: 1873 ExecStart=/usr/sbin/smbd --foreground --no-process-group $SMBDOPTIONS (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)
 Main PID: 1873 (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)

Nov 07 17:05:30 kodi systemd[1]: Starting Samba SMB Daemon...
Nov 07 17:05:30 kodi systemd[1]: smbd.service: Main process exited, code=exited, status=1/FAILURE
Nov 07 17:05:30 kodi systemd[1]: smbd.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
Nov 07 17:05:30 kodi systemd[1]: Failed to start Samba SMB Daemon.
dpkg: error processing package samba (--configure):
 installed samba package post-installation script subprocess returned error exit status 1
Processing triggers for libc-bin (2.27-3ubuntu1) ...
Errors were encountered while processing:
 samba
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
fmf@kodi:~$
```

I tried to remove completely samba with `apt remove --purge samba` and reinstall it from scratch, but still no luck.
I also removed the `/etc/samba/smb.conf` file and tried again, still no luck.
Rebooted, still no luck.

```
fmf@kodi:~$ lsb_release -a
No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 18.04.1 LTS
Release:        18.04
Codename:       bionic
fmf@kodi:~$
fmf@kodi:~$ samba
[2018/11/07 17:04:05.862379,  0] ../lib/util/debug.c:1053(reopen_logs_internal)
  Unable to open new log file '/var/log/samba/log.samba': No such file or directory
[2018/11/07 17:04:05.862951,  0] ../source4/smbd/server.c:448(binary_smbd_main)
  samba version 4.7.6-Ubuntu started.
  Copyright Andrew Tridgell and the Samba Team 1992-2017
```

Any suggestion?

EDIT
As requested in the comment:

```
fmf@kodi:~$ grep smbd /var/log/auth.log
Nov  7 16:34:44 kodi sudo:      fmf : TTY=pts/2 ; PWD=/home/fmf ; USER=root ; COMMAND=/bin/systemctl status smbd.service
Nov  7 16:36:10 kodi sudo:      fmf : TTY=pts/2 ; PWD=/home/fmf ; USER=root ; COMMAND=/bin/systemctl status smbd.service
Nov  7 16:37:26 kodi sudo:      fmf : TTY=pts/2 ; PWD=/home/fmf ; USER=root ; COMMAND=/usr/sbin/service smbd restart
Nov  7 16:41:12 kodi sudo:      fmf : TTY=pts/2 ; PWD=/home/fmf ; USER=root ; COMMAND=/usr/sbin/service smbd restart
Nov  7 16:46:19 kodi sudo:      fmf : TTY=pts/2 ; PWD=/home/fmf ; USER=root ; COMMAND=/usr/sbin/dpkg-reconfigure smbd
Nov  7 16:46:44 kodi sudo:      fmf : TTY=pts/2 ; PWD=/home/fmf ; USER=root ; COMMAND=/usr/sbin/dpkg-reconfigure smbd
Nov  7 16:47:26 kodi sudo:      fmf : TTY=pts/2 ; PWD=/home/fmf ; USER=root ; COMMAND=/usr/sbin/service smbd stop
Nov  7 16:47:50 kodi sudo:      fmf : TTY=pts/2 ; PWD=/home/fmf ; USER=root ; COMMAND=/usr/bin/apt install smbd
Nov  7 17:07:41 kodi sudo:      fmf : TTY=pts/0 ; PWD=/home/fmf ; USER=root ; COMMAND=/usr/bin/dpkg --install smbd
Nov  8 11:00:57 kodi sudo:      fmf : TTY=pts/2 ; PWD=/home/fmf ; USER=root ; COMMAND=/usr/sbin/service smbd restart
fmf@kodi:~$
```

I don't see anything wrong here, am I right?

Answer (score 3):

Same problem in fedora 29, docker container.

At least in the docker container the issue is the logging is now down with the service bus, which doesn't work...

The solution was to change my configuration to start with `-i` flag.  e.g.

```
/sbin/smbd -i -F
```

and

```
/sbin/nmbd -i -F
```

Then the log goes to the console, which works normally.

Chances are the Ubuntu issue is also a failing to log problem.

Comment: This command helped me to see error in my old config file, even if it was not needed to change tervice starting configuration.

Answer (score 1):

This may be a bug as reported [here on the Debian bug tracker](https://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/bugreport.cgi?bug=909465) :

You might try to remove the winbind package and try again.

```
sudo apt-get remove winbind
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get dist-upgrade
```

Answer (score 0):

Same problem in Ubuntu server 22.04.
The solution was create a new file share, then run:

```
smbd start
```